# Execute Query Inside Column From CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a CTE table which returns dynamic SQL.

Here is my CTE query:

```
DECLARE @Qry VARCHAR(MAX)

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        Qry = 'UPDATE data_'+ REPLACE(mrp.father_uid, '-', '_')+' SET done = 2 WHERE uid = '''+    CAST(mrp.uid AS VARCHAR(250)) + ''''
    FROM  
        [4928_MyProcessDB].dbo.main_result_process mrp WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN  
        [4928_MyProcessDB].dbo.main_result_process_part mrpp WITH (NOLOCK) ON mrp.uid = mrpp.process_uid
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
```

which returns:

[image]

I want to execute each row on the CTE table. How can I do that?

Comment: Loop through the returned rows one and a time and call `sp_executesql`.

Comment: `NOLOCK` is not a go-faster switch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With just a couple of tweaks

```
DECLARE @Qry VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        Qry = ';UPDATE data_'+ REPLACE(mrp.father_uid, '-', '_')+' SET done = 2 WHERE uid = '''+    CAST(mrp.uid AS VARCHAR(250)) + ''''
    FROM  
        [4928_MyProcessDB].dbo.main_result_process mrp WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN  
        [4928_MyProcessDB].dbo.main_result_process_part mrpp WITH (NOLOCK) ON mrp.uid = mrpp.process_uid
)
SELECT @Qry = @Qry + Qry
FROM CTE

Exec(@Qry)
```

Comment: Don't forget `QUOTENAME`